# What are the options for getting feedback from text area?

Tags: php, javascript, textarea, user-feedback

My page has a text area and a submit button and I want to take feedback from the users of the page. What are my options? I can think of two:

- Send the contents of the text area as e-mail. (too much effort and connections).
- Save the contents to a local txt file. (seems legit).

Are there any other useful methods for this purpose? If so what are they? Can you provide a link which explains how to implement those solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: Use a database, it will be more "legit" than a plain text file. You will be able to perform checks, statistics, filters, spam blocking, and so on.

Comment: You don't want to know how to send feedback, but how to receive it. I would store it in a database and set up a cron job to notify me of new feedback every so often.

Comment: *"Send the contents of the text area as e-mail. (too much effort and connections)."* ... come on, seriously? Too much "effort" and "connections"? Can you clarify what you mean by that? I mean, you're asking how to build a contact form - there's *loads* of tutorials etc on the web. How about "send an email **and** save to a database"?

Comment: @WesleyMurch I am very new to this topic, so it seems like too much effort to me to establish a server connection for sending e mails. That was what i meant.

Comment: @Eggplant seems like a better solution. Is it worth involving a database? My page is very simple and has no many visitors.

Comment: @Volkanİlbeyli It's OK to have your script send emails. Stop worrying about performance until you can comprehend it. A contact form is practically the "Hello World" of web forms.

Comment: If there aren't many visitors you could just live with an email system, which is actually easy to implement: [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php). If you want to take the chance to  acquire some experience working with databases, then this is also a good way to begin with. Maybe it's not "worth" now in term of performance and utility gains, but it surely is for your knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for the input Eggplant and Wesley.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably save the results of the textarea into your database rather than a text file or an email.  You can write a simple admin script to read the results when you want to.  here's an tutorial if you're unfamiliar with reading from / writing to dbs http://teamtutorials.com/web-development-tutorials/php-tutorials/inserting-data-into-a-mysql-database-using-php#.USuc76Wsh8E

Comment: reputation concerns:) Yes Brad, I will as soon as I can. Have to wait 9 minutes after an answer is given to accept it.